# Node fs Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open

Tags: node.js, fs

I get this error in my app:

> Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Full Menu\db\main.json'

The app I have is built with electron-boilerplate. I am using this function to get the path to the root of the app:

```
path.dirname(process.execPath)
```

And this is the script that writes the file:

```
fs.writeFile(apath + '/db/' + elem + '.json', JSON.stringify(results)
```

I know what the problem is: permissions. But how could I get this working without running the app as an administrator?

Comment: Giving full permissions to the dir where it should write the file.

Comment: I have the same issue in my window 11. I have deleted the same file and then laravel recreate the same and it works.

Answer (score 53):

For the benefit of searchers; I has this error. I added full permissions for `Everyone` as a test, but that didn't fix it. The issue was that the file was set to `readonly` (by source control).

Unchecking the `readonly` option in the file properties fixed the issue.

Comment: This is the current fix that I am having to do at the moment. TFS + VS2015 marks the file as `readonly` when you check anything in and this breaks my gulp build script. Marking the files as not being readonly solves the issue, though it does make VS complain a lot about the files saying that there is an `Existing or non-version controlled version of the file`. Be careful with this as you may lose changes or even files when getting latest version.

Comment: Also had this issue, required to use Perforce (pray for me) and it regularly sets to read only when syncing files. Right Click > Untick Read Only fixed the issue.

Answer (score 21):

On my Windows 10 machine, I encountered this error when running an old Node JS project. I think Node version 10.16.

In any case, it was trying to modify a dotfile in my project. Be sure that the file isn't hidden on Windows. After unchecking the hidden option in the file properties pop up. Everything worked.

So to fix:

1. Right click file in Windows Explorer
2. Select properties
3. Uncheck **Hidden**
4. Click **Ok**
5. Re-run your command.

[image]

Comment: Why does this have any effect on whether you can read from or write to a file?

Comment: @Clonkex -- Because your app needs the hidden file, but when it's set as "Hidden", it means it's not allowed to be opened. So if you uncheck the "Hidden" property, your app can use it now, although your app doesn't really OPEN it, but only USES it.

Comment: @WilliamHou Well yeah, but I guess I'm asking why the "hidden" attribute has any effect on reading and writing. It's just a marker for directory listings. It should have zero impact on reading and writing. That's just nonsensical. The attribute isn't called "read-only" or "protected".

Comment: @Clonkex Oh, I see what you mean. The hidden file is actually what VSCode does behind the scenes, which is why it's HIDDEN. VSCode DEFINITELY OPENS and USES the hidden file for its basic settings, but it OPENS it behind the scene. That's why we cannot see it. But it does impact your app.

Answer (score 15):

If you have the file that you can't open or modify mounted as a volume in docker restarting docker should fix the issue.

Answer (score 10):

i had to run the node command prompt as administrator and that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 6):

I face this issue when I was deleting a file/folder.

**Solution:**

Just restart your code editor/ terminal
Or 
Restart your computer

Answer (score 4):

If you are facing this issue on Windows 10, then please try the following:

1. Uncheck **readonly** options for the folder (if read-only reverts, login as administrator)
2. Open terminal **as administrator** (if you are facing this issue on terminal)
3. **Switch off ransomware** folder protection
4. Change **chmod** of the folder
5. Check if the folder is **hidden** or not
6. Disable antivirus protection (**temporarily**) and try this
7. Or move your project folder somewhere else, where antivirus ransomware protection is disable.

If nothing above works, then try the following:
https://appuals.com/how-to-fix-folder-keeps-reverting-to-read-only-on-windows-10/.

Hope this would of help.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you must change the permissions recursively to the file so the user executing your script can read / write this file.

https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod

Comment: I solved the problem by changing the NSIS script so it will allow me to choose another installation folder.

Answer (score 1):

Restarting my computer fixed this problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue too.  I'm using TFS (or VSO, Azure DevOps, etc.) for source control.  I was trying to compile from .scss to .css and it couldn't open my .css.  I just needed to right-click on my .css file and Check Out for Edit...

Answer (score 0):

I had the error because i have already open the file before

```
var stream = fs.createWriteStream(outputFileName, {flags:'a'})
var output = fs.createWriteStream(outputFileName, {flags:'a'})
```

Answer (score 0):

*this is not an exact answer but may help:*

**i think** if you want to `read` or `readSync` a file that doesn't exist you will encounter an `EPERM` error...

> in many programming languages, any permission related error may not
>   directly means an actual permission issue

for example in `PHP` Folders (not files) must delete by php `rmdir()` method but if you want to do that with `unlink()` , u will encountered with a wrong Warning message that says "permission denied"

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem using the following software:

- Windows 10
- GitBash
- Node v19

I was able to solve it opening GitBash as admin

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, when i tried to create and write to a file using NodeJS. I thought it had to do with my windows file/folder access permissions, but after restarting my computer and running the code again, I still got the same error.

[image]

[image]

However, this time around my antivirus gave me a pop-up message also, stating that it blocked permission for **Node.exe** to write or open files. So once I flagged Node.exe as safe for my anti-virus program (Avast).

It worked for me. Disabling my antivirus could've also temporarily fixed it, I guess.

Answer (score -3):

> If you use windows 10, you must turn off Ransomware protection. Ransomware protection will prevent all folder and file changes.You can turn off it in Windows Security Center. See screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Even if this did fix this issue it'd be risky.  Don't make it easier for attackers to ransomware your system.  Find another way.