# 'Eperm: operation not permitted' when using multer

Tags: reactjs, express, youtube-api, react-bootstrap, multer

I'm attempting to pass a video file from my front end (using React and Axios) and upload it to youtube from my backend using express (using this tutorial https://youtu.be/xhiWEpU-h-A). The file gets submitted in the form of a 'formdata' object from my front end.

Here's my backend

```
const oAuth = youtube.authenticate({type: 'oauth',client_id: credentials.web.client_id,client_secret: credentials.web.client_secret,//Redirect uris has not been set up, may cause errors
redirect_url: credentials.web.redirect_uris[0]

})

const storage = multer.diskStorage({destination: '/',filename(req, file, cb) {const newFileName = ${uuid()}-${file.originalname}cb(null,newFileName);}})

const uploadVideoFile = multer({storage: storage}).single("videoFile");

app.post('/api/uploadVideo', uploadVideoFile, (req, res)=>{

console.log("upload video endpoint established")console.log(file was set to: ${req.file})if(req.file)console.log('we found a file')

else
console.log('no file?')console.log(title: ${title} description: ${description})return;

//ignore the stuff below here
```

Here's the function that submits the formdata on the front end, as well as the state variables

```
const uploadVideo = ()=>{

//uploadVideo(Credentials, [{}])

  const videoData = new FormData()
  videoData.append("videoFile", videoFile)
  videoData.append("title", videoTitle)
  videoData.append("description", videoDescription)


  console.log(videoData)
  
  Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/api/uploadVideo", videoData).then((response) =>{
    console.log(response.data)
  })
}
    const [videoTitle, setVideoTitle] = useState('')
const [videoMode, setVideoMode] =  useState(true)
const [videoFile, setVideoFile] = useState(null)`
```

And here's the form object that accepts the video file

```
          <Form.Control type="file" accept="video/mp4" disabled={!videoMode} onChange={(e)=>{setVideoFile(e.target.files[0])}}>

   </Form.Control>`
```

When I attempt to run the function I get the following error message on my server

`Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\fb434fe2-e46c-4d8c-8f41-7b807f1b92a7-Column test - Google Chrome 2022-01-12 17-27-21.mp4'`

the error occurs before the post request can be resolved

I was hoping multer would be able to locate the file I passed to it but I simply get a permission error.

Comment: Not familiar with multer, but, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42862128/12511801). Consider (*if you haven't*), search on google or Stack Overflow about `Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open` and see if you can try the given workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the error by setting up Multer again and using the default settings from the documentation

```
const upload = multer({dest: "uploads/"});//uploads to "uploads" folder on my server


//post request

app.post('/api/uploadVideo', upload.single("videoFile"), (req, res)=>{
const {title, description} = req.body;
  console.log("upload video endpoint established")
  console.log(`file destination was set to: ${req.file.destination}`)
  //return
```